# Comma-first Java formatting in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Does IntelliJ IDEA (`2018.2+`) offer the formatting option for comma-first style in Java?

```
public void example(
      String one
      , String two
      , String three) { ... }
```

I've read about it somewhere but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: It would probably be under `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Method declaration parameters` but I have none there

Comment: @Lino yeah I checked too but found nothing

Comment: I just found this [thread on jetbrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206346899-Comma-first-style) but also there it's just a feature request as it seems

Comment: Isn't 'Keep when reformatting - Line Breaks' enough?

Comment: @Lino they need one for every product. I think there is none for Java. Might open it.

Comment: @vp_arth I've always had this setting checked but unfortunately it doesn't work for this style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option at the moment. Please vote for the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6965

Comment: Done. Thank you!